# How to execute python script using CherryPy framework

Tags: python-3.x, cherrypy

I've been working on side project to learn python coding better.
Since I reciantly started college I've been eager to learn more abut the language that we work with.

So basicly I am using Raspberry Pi to work with in school and out.
Reciantly I had an idea by using ultrasound sensor to detect the distance of object(in this case hand) to light up setted up LED in regards of the objects distance. Basicly I got the code working and seperatly it does work. But I'm here for a different reason.

I want to implament it to the CherryPy webserver, that I could activate the sensor to start it's work, afterwards deactivate by pressing other button in web interface. Everything needs to be controlled in web interface with html butons.

Any ideas or anything feell free to post them.
Any more questions please ask.

```
import cherrypy
#import blink
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime

from subprocess import check_output
ipaddr = check_output(['hostname','-I']).strip().decode('utf-8')

file = open('/home/pi/htmlfile.html')
index_html = file.read()
file.close()
index_html = index_html.format(IP=ipaddr)

class HelloWorld(object):
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):
    return index_html

@cherrypy.expose
def goat(self):
    return "There is no goats here!"

@cherrypy.expose
def blink(self):
    #os.system("blink.py 1")
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
    #GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
    #GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)
    i = 0
    while (i<8):
        GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
        #GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
        #GPIO.output(27, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
        #GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
        #GPIO.output(27, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        i = i+1
    return "Blinking finished"

@cherrypy.expose
def yellowon(self):
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
    return index_html

@cherrypy.expose
def off(self):
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(27, GPIO.LOW)
    return index_html

@cherrypy.expose
def greenon(self):
    GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
    return index_html

@cherrypy.expose
def redon(self):
    GPIO.output(27, GPIO.HIGH)
    return index_html

@cherrypy.expose
def sensoron(self):
    def reading(sensor):
        pingtime = 0
        echotime = 0

        if sensor == 0:
            GPIO.output(21,GPIO.LOW)

        if(GPIO.input(18)==1):
            print("HIGH")
        else:
            print("LOW")

            GPIO.output(21,GPIO.HIGH)
            pingtime=time.time()
            time.sleep(0.00001)
            GPIO.output(21,GPIO.LOW)

            while GPIO.input(16)==0:
                pingtime = time.time()

            while GPIO.input(16)==1:
                echotime=time.time()

            if (echotime is not None) and (pingtime is not None):
                elapsedtime = echotime - pingtime
                distance = elapsedtime * 17000
            else:
                distance = 0

                #print(pingtime)
                #print(echotime)

            if distance < 10:
                GPIO.output(4,GPIO.HIGH)
                GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
                GPIO.output(27,GPIO.LOW)
            #print("AMBER")
            elif distance < 20 and distance >= 10:
                GPIO.output(4,GPIO.LOW)
                GPIO.output(17,GPIO.HIGH)
                GPIO.output(27,GPIO.LOW)
            #print("GREEN")
            elif distance >= 20:
                GPIO.output(4,GPIO.LOW)
                GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
                GPIO.output(27,GPIO.HIGH)
            #print("RED") 

            return distance
    return index_html
    file = open('/home/pi/new.py')
    return index_html

@cherrypy.expose
def sensoroff(self):
    def reading(sensor):
        pingtime = 0
        echotime = 0
        GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(27, GPIO. LOW)
    file.close()
    return index_html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)
    cherrypy.server.socket_host = ipaddr
    cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Thank you for help in advance :)

Comment: You should probably (1) implement a [`cherrypy plugin`](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/extend.html#plugins) for the purpose of controlling your sensors and doing other logic and (2) to some asynchronous calls running subroutines controlling the hardware. But keep in mind to return from handler function then. Everything long-running should not block HTTP handling.

Comment: And I'd recommend you using some template engine (e.g. `Jinja2`) for rendering HTML representation.